# Model-layer validation in Doctrine, Symfony

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have a schema.yml containing something similiar to the following:

```
Character:
  tableName: characters 
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, notblank: true, minlength: 3 }
```

I define the minlength of the column name to be 3. I created a unit test to test the minlength validation, and I found out that the validation is not working.

```
$character = new Character();
$character->set('name', 'Dw');
$t->ok(! $character->isValid()); # This test failed
```

Can someone tell me what might be the problem here?

Thanks,
Andree

Answer (score 5):

I found it.

Doctrine's validation is turned off by default, so you have to turned it on using the following code:

```
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_VALIDATE, Doctrine::VALIDATE_ALL);
```

In Symfony, I add the following code to /config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php

```
  public function configureDoctrine(Doctrine_Manager $manager) 
  { 
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_VALIDATE, Doctrine::VALIDATE_ALL);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Andree's answer is working, but there's other, a bit simlier way to turn on Doctrine's validation.

Add this into your databases.yml config file:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    param:
      attributes:
        validate: validate_all
```